# Массив из букв ['A' .. 'Z'] и Edit

Tags: delphi

В функции, у меня, **CU := ['A' .. 'Z'];**

**Вопрос:** Ка правильно подключить **Edit** что бы - **CU := Form1.Edit1.Text**. 
Если так пишу, то получаю ошибку в виде: **E2010 Incompatible types: 'TSysCharSet' and 'TCaption'**

Понимаю что ошибка мелочная но чего то застряла...

```
function IsGood(AInpStr: String; AMinLen, AMaxLen: Integer;
  AAlowOnlyLetters: Boolean = True): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
  a: Boolean;
  Len: Integer;
  CU, CL: TSysCharSet;
begin

  Result := False;
  Len := Length(AInpStr);

  /// ///// Вот тут нужно заменить
  /// ///// то есть (CU := Form1.Edit1.Text)
  CU := ['A' .. 'Z'];

  if AAlowOnlyLetters then
  begin
    for i := 1 to Len do
    begin
      a := CharInSet(AInpStr[i], CU);
      .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .
```

Comment: мне кажется будет проще написать `if AInpStr[i]>='A' and AInpStr[i]>='Z'` или что-то вроде этого.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Меня то функция устраивает, просто не могу понять как edit вставить правильно что бы в нем задавать параметры букв.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CU := [];
for i := 1 to Length(Form1.Edit1.Text) do
begin
  Include(CU, Form1.Edit1.Text[i]);
end;
```